# OFFICE APPS FOR SHAREPOINT SERVER 2019

Tags: sharepoint-server

So i just recently installed and configured SharePoint server 2019. so i uploaded documents in the new library i created but i cant seem to edit office docs on the server without downloading, editing and re-uploading file. I want to know if there is a way to edit documents just like SharePoint online office apps edition. With the new SharePoint version a lot has changed. Do i need Microsoft Office SharePoint Server (MOSS) or what configuration are my missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SharePoint Online offers inline editing functionality out of the box way. However when it comes to the SharePoint On-Premises environment, we had to install Office WebApps in the past (SharePoint 2013 days) for this purpose. Later in SharePoint 2016, Office Online Server was introduced. OOS is the successor to Office Web Apps Server 2013. SharePoint 2019 continues to use Office Online Server.

Refer to this article for more:
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/52608.office-online-server-for-sharepoint-server-2019.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You need to install [Office Online Server](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/officeonlineserver/office-online-server) on another server and bind it to your farm.

The requirements, installation instructions, etc. are at the above link. All of your users must be licensed for Office 365 desktop or Office Pro Plus in order for you to get this from the Volume Licensing service center.